# HTTP connection with timeout under Java 1.5

Tags: java, http, timeout

I have developed a simple low-level access to a web service by using java.net.HttpURLConnection.

I need to set a timeout for connection and reading, and this seems to be possible under Java 1.6 and up, but for Java 1.5 I'm completely at a loss.

Is there any replacement for HttpURLConnection that can serve my needs?

My code right now is like this:

```
        oURL = new URL( this.endpoint );
        httpCon = (HttpURLConnection)oURL.openConnection();

        httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
        httpCon.setDoInput(true);

        httpCon.setConnectTimeout( this.connect_timeout );
        httpCon.setReadTimeout( this.read_timeout );

        httpCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        httpCon.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", this.endpoint+"#"+req.getOperationName());


        reqStream = httpCon.getOutputStream();
        reqStream.write( reqXML.getBytes());
```

Once I read the response from the output stream, I'm done. However, the implementation of HttpURLConnection under 1.5 seems to lack the two relevant methods.

Comment: Are you using jdk 1.5 ? or jdk 1.4 ?

Comment: It's running under Java 1.5

Comment: But in 1.5 it has the two methods http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html

Comment: So I thought, but the particular subclass HttpURLConnection, even though it derives from URLConnection, seems to lack both methods in 1.5

Comment: All of you are completely right... I took the word of my customer for granted... the application server is running under 1.4

Comment: I solved this by using Apache HTTP Client 3.x, which is end of life but fully compatible with Java 1.4 and pretty straighforward to use. I'll prepare an example of the code with which I replaced the one shown here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're not using JDK 1.5, I created a java (1.5) project in eclipse and it allows me to use both methods.

```
    HttpURLConnection a = (HttpURLConnection)new URL("URL").openConnection();
    a.setConnectTimeout(0);
    a.setReadTimeout(0);
```

and in the description of the methods it says it's since 1.5

**setConnectTimeout**

> Sets a specified timeout value, in milliseconds, to be used when
>   opening a communications link to the resource referenced by this
>   URLConnection. If the timeout expires before the connection can be
>   established, a java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised. A timeout of
>   zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout.
>
> Some non-standard implementation of this method may ignore the
>   specified timeout. To see the connect timeout set, please call
>   getConnectTimeout().
>
> Parameters: timeout an int that specifies the connect timeout value in
>   milliseconds Throws: IllegalArgumentException - if the timeout
>   parameter is negative **Since:**
>   **1.5**

**setReadTimeout**

> Sets the read timeout to a specified timeout, in milliseconds. A
>   non-zero value specifies the timeout when reading from Input stream
>   when a connection is established to a resource. If the timeout expires
>   before there is data available for read, a
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised. A timeout of zero is
>   interpreted as an infinite timeout.
>
> Some non-standard implementation of this method ignores the specified
>   timeout. To see the read timeout set, please call getReadTimeout().
>
> Parameters: timeout an int that specifies the timeout value to be used
>   in milliseconds Throws: IllegalArgumentException - if the timeout
>   parameter is negative **Since:**
>   **1.5**

You can also see the API docs from oracle

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout(int)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

It says **HttpURLConnection** inherits from **URLConnection** and the two methods are **public** so they are in the  **HttpURLConnection** class.

Comment: Oh my, you're completely right... I have made tests under the production application server and it is running under 1.4, yet according to my customer, it is 1.5...
I wonder if I can just rename this question or void it... because it is useless, I am afraid :(